# Windows shortcut or batch file to open command prompt in ruby directory with a pre populated string

Tags: ruby, batch-file, cmd, compass-geolocation

I have just started using Compass within Ruby on Windows. In order to watch a directory for changes, I need to run cmd.exe in the Ruby directory and then use the command "compass watch C:\path\to\project".

I wish to make a shortcut that will open cmd.exe in D:\ruby\bin\ (Ruby directory) with a pre-filled string that I can simply complete and then press enter to execute. For example:

```
C:\ruby\bin>compass watch D:\path\to\_
```

...and then I simply type the project folder name and press enter.

- I can create a shortcut that runs cmd.exe in C:\ruby\bin\ but I then have to type the rest.
- I can create a batch file that runs cmd.exe in its default location and then changes directory to C:\ruby\bin, then executes `compass watch C:\path\to\project`
- I **can't** figure out how to pre-fill the above command and have cmd.exe wait for me to input the relevant project directory before manually pressing enter to execute.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty simple one liner...

1. Open Notepad or other text editor
2. Change directory (cd) to your Ruby directory
3. Execute 'compass watch'

   cd C:\ruby\bin
   compass watch
4. Go to Save As
5. Change 'Save as type' to 'All files'
6. Save as compass.bat
7. Run the file (double-click) to start polling for changes

Source http://omnitech-support.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/how-to-create-batch-files-for-windows-8.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new shortcut wherever you want to be able to run it.
2. For the command line enter `cmd /K compass watch`.
3. Call it whatever you like (I suggest 'Compass Watch') and save it.
4. Right click on it and choose properties.
5. Change the "Start In" to the folder where your config.rb is.
6. You can also set the "Run" option to Minimized.
7. Save the changes to the shortcut.
8. Run the shortcut to set Compass watching for changes in the relevant files in the folders defined in your config.rb.